# Store data automatically at the end of checkout with OPC prestashop

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, onepage-checkout

I need to find a solution for the checkout with OnePageCheckoutPs.

When a user logged add data, like delivery and invoice, he must not force to click on the 'Update' button for store the datas but it should do directly at the conclusion of the order.

In the screenshot what i need...

1 The customer insert data of delivery et invoice, normally for store this data he has to clcik on 'Aggiorna dati fatturazione' (Update => #btn_update_address_delivery) but i need that this is doing automatically on clicking on the button 3.

2 In the moment he edit a invoice address, it should happen the same thing of point 1...

3 I thought that a practique solution is when click on the button 3, automatically he click (maybe with jquery) on the button 1 and 2..But i try to edit the code with no success...

I suppose that this should be done in the method placeOrder() or onepagecheckout.js, but i can't find a solution for this...Someone can help me?

Here is when the form is submitted

```
                    if ($rc_page !== 'identity') {
                    if (Validate::isLoadedObject($address_delivery)) {
                        if ($this->config_vars['OPC_USE_SAME_NAME_CONTACT_DA']) {
                            $address_delivery->firstname = $customer->firstname;
                            $address_delivery->lastname  = $customer->lastname;
                        }
                        //Here i should get the input that is not submitted
                        
                        $address_delivery->update();

                    }
```

[image]